Getting `Input("rpc finalized_head failed.")` while running try-runtime
I am trying to verify runtime-upgrade through try-runtime against a live environment using below commands:
cargo build --release --features try-runtime

try-runtime --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/dev-runtime/dev_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm \
          on-runtime-upgrade --disable-idempotency-checks live --uri wss://rpc.devnet.network:443  


But I am getting below error:
[2024-08-05T11:04:56Z ERROR remote-ext] Error = Transport(Request rejected `502`)
thread 'main' panicked at cli/main.rs:324:10:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Input("rpc finalized_head failed.")
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


Can someone please help me to fix this?
